# Storing the output of a shell command in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to store the output of a command as follows:

```
sh abc_port=$("find ./ -type f -name '*.yml' -exec grep abc_solution_portbase: {} \; | cut -d: -f2")
```

However, it fails:

```
-bash: find ./ -type f -name '*.yml' -exec grep abc_solution_portbase: {} \; | cut -d: -f2: No such file or directory
```

I also tried something like this:

```
"find ./ -type f -name '*.yml' -exec grep abc_solution_portbase: {} \; | cut -d: -f2" <<< $abc_port
```

But it did not return anything.

Did I miss something, or are these kinds of expressions appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I would express it as follows:

```
abc_port="$(find ./ -type f -name '*.yml' \
  -exec grep abc_solution_portbase: {} \; | cut -d: -f2)"
```

*Note, the main idea is to wrap the `$()` expression in double quotes: `variable_name="$(your_command)"`. The command within `$()` is not supposed to solve your specific YML parsing problem.*

**Explanation**

You need the quotes around `$()` expression in the assignment, because the `$()` expression may return a sequence interpreted as a shell expression. For example, the following is an invalid assignment:

```
$ a=x y
bash: y: command not found
```

To assign `x y` string, you need double or single quotes:

```
a="x y"
```

Read the answers to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) question for more details.

### Regarding your attempts

1. `sh abc_port=$(the_command)`

According to the `sh` manual:

> ```
> sh [−abCefhimnuvx] [−o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
>            [command_file [argument...]]
> ```
>
> The sh utility is a command language interpreter that shall execute
>   commands read from a command line string, the standard input, or a
>   specified file.

the `sh` utility interprets the `abc_port=<result_of_the_command>` sequence a an input file. You can test it simply:

```
$ echo 'echo hello' > 'a=b'
$ sh a=b
hello
```

2. `"the_command"`

This is just a quoted argument. The first argument is interpreted as a command to be executed. So the shell tries to find `the_command` executable in `$PATH` and launch it. You can wrap any argument in double quotes, if you like. For example, `"ls" -l` has the same effect as `ls -l`.

Comment: It return something like
find: paths must precede expression:  -exec

Comment: @Lee, the main idea is to wrap `$()` in double quotes. Maybe you need the `./` in the `find` command. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try with cat with grep 
ex-

```
abc_port=$("find ./ -type f -name '*.yml' -exec cat {} \;|grep abc_solution_portbase: | cut -d: -f2")
```

Comment: I've tried, it return -bash: find ./ -type f -name '*.yml' -exec cat {} \;|grep abc_solution_portbase: | cut -d: -f2: No such file or directory. Same error i get before

Comment: use cut -d ':' -f2